# Java : Object access with private fields

Tags: java, arrays, oop

This are my two classes. Eclipse, underlines myGrid[0] inside while-loop and I get a message "*The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Grid*". Appreciate any help.

```
public class Grid {
  private int[][] myGrid;
  private int x, y;

  public Grid(int x, int y) {
    myGrid = new int[y][x];
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play {

  private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  private void setPosition (Grid myGrid) {
    boolean counter = false;

    while (counter == false) {
      System.out.println("Give a position, from 0 to " + myGrid[0].length-1 + " : >");
      x = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing the Grid class with its myGrid field. They are completely different. Just because you give your Grid parameter the same name as its field, it's not the same thing. myGrid is a Grid variable pure and simple, and not an array.

Comment: To diagnose the problem instead of posting an SO question, maybe you shouldn't use variable names more than once to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just because two variables have the same name, doesn't make them the same variable. You have defined two different variables with the same name.

Comment: Consider what you would have written in the print line if your method signature were `private void setPosition (Grid mg ) `

Comment: @engineer dude the variable is private!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the Grid class with its myGrid field. They are completely different. Just because you give your Grid parameter the same name as its field, it's not the same thing. myGrid is a Grid variable pure and simple, and not an array.

Here:

```
private void setPosition (Grid myGrid) {
```

myGrid is a Grid variable and is not an array and cannot be treated as such. If this were my code, I'd give the Grid class a `getColumnCount()` method

```
public class Grid {
    private int[][] myGrid;
    private int x, y;

    public Grid(int x, int y) {
        myGrid = new int[y][x];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return myGrid.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return myGrid[0].length;
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
private void setPosition (Grid myGrid) {
    boolean counter = false;

    while (!counter) {
        System.out.println("Give a position, from 0 to " + (myGrid.getColumnCount() - 1) + " : >");
        x = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    }
}
```